# DataGrip display full geometry

Tags: postgis, jetbrains-ide, datagrip, intellij-datagrip

How can I load the full geometry in JetBrains DataGrip ?

[image]

Why do I get 204 KB loaded when total is 1.75 MB. Due to this record not displayed on Geo Viewer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was implemented to prevent OOM issues.

Go to `Preferences` → `Database` → `Data Views` and set desired values for `Max LOB length (bytes)`

[image: Max LOB length (bytes)]